# File Reader Format

Tags: java

This project I'm working on, here is the function which write data's in to file :

```
    public void writetofile(){
    String bucky[]={custname,custlname,agee,address,id};
    for(int i = 0; i < bucky.length; i++) {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new        FileWriter("records.txt", true))) {
             String s;
             s = bucky[i];
             bw.write(s);
             bw.newLine();
             bw.flush();
         }

         catch(IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error In File");
      }
     }
   };
```

and there is another function defined which reads data's from file ,

```
    public void filereader (){
    int i=0;
    Object[] options = {"OK"};
    try
    {
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("records.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
   {
   sb.append(strLine +"\n");
   }
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, sb.toString());
   }catch(Exception e){
   JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Error", "Customers",    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
   }

   };
```

and the problem is , let's say I want to create an account for a customer in my project , so few questions were asked such as name , last name , gender , etc. and all those info's have been saved , but when I try to read files all the data's will appear in no format , I want them to be appear in the proper way like this :

```
customer name : Michelle , 
gender : Female ;
```

but right now it appears as this :

```
michelle , 
female ,
```

Comment: That's how data will be stored in a file. You can create a class which has all these fields and after reading each line from your file, you can split it and populate an object of that class and add it to a list. Keep repeating this till you've read the whole file. And then you can override the `toString()` method in your class which will print the data in the format you want! :)

Comment: You need to change your writer to support the format that you want.  You could also consider using XML or even a light weight database

Comment: I would like to be explained with a segment of code , I'm not as good as you guys are, so these things makes me a little confused

Comment: Do you just want to format the output (that you show on the screen) or the file format itself...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the desired output first and call`bw.write(s);` only once

or follow R.J 's suggestion. Put everything to an object and override `toString` methid of that class. This will be the perfect way of solving your problem

```
        import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Customer
    {

        private final String firstName;

        private final String lastName;

        private final String address;

        private final int    age;

        private final int    id;

        public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String address, int age,
                int id)
        {
            super();
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.address = address;
            this.age = age;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString ()
        {
            return "Customer [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
                    + ", address=" + address + ", age=" + age + "]";
        }

        public static void main (String[] args)
        {

        }

        public void writetofile (String custname, String custlname, int agee,
                String address, int age)
        {

            Customer customer = new Customer(custname, custlname, address, age, id);
            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                    "records.txt", true)))
            {
                String s = customer.toString();
                bw.write(s);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
            }

            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error In File");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Isn't that what the OP is already doing...the output and input formats do not match...

Comment: No he is not formatting the line before writing and he is calling bw.write(s); in a loop.